# Code to listen for changes in a pywinauto Listbox

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm using *pywinauto* to interact with the window of an old game - specifically the dedicated server GUI. I've been able to connect to it with:

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\___.exe")
```

Using a loop, I'm able to read each line in a *Listbox* in a specific window using:

```
for i in dlg.ListBox.descendants():
    print (i.window_text())
```

The *Listbox* behaves as like a console output area and I've also been able to write commands to the *Edit* (input) field which appear in the *Listbox*.

All of this is great considering I didn't think it would be easy at all!

However, the last part of what I'd like to do is proving more difficult...
**I want to listen for changes in the list box so I can react to them and write different responses back into the *Listbox*.** So for example, when a player joins the server, I want my code to know that a new line has appeared in the *Listbox* (so I can write a custom welcome message to the **Edit** field).

I have tried to look at listener scripts but I feel a bit out of my depth and can't seem to find a  simple code example that could help me accomplish this. Does anyone have any ideas where I could look or what I could use?
Even better... would anyone be able to provide some sample code for me to re-work?